# Android multithreading for services

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 2 tasks first is get the periodic location update and at the same time 
update the timer.
If I run one thread for update the location and other for the timer,Is this is good design or not?
If yes then how should I approach the solution i.e.use handler/asyncTask ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have work queue like refresh location for every 60 seconds then  [Intentservice](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the ony Tasks which should work i would suggest to run locationUpdates inside ActivityThread, while a Timer is run in its own Thread anyways (though the `TimerTask{ run() }` implementation.)
This is the best answer I can serve with as long as I don't know more infos, what you have tried, and what you want t o archive